# TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float Fix

Tags: python, opencv

I am using the source script for the Canny edge detector. It doesn't to be working. Here is the full script:

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
edges = cv.Canny(img,100,200)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

The error message is TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float.
How would one fix this, and why does this happen?

Full error code:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\opencv scripts\cat\opencvproject.py", line 6, in <module>
    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2896, in imshow
    __ret = gca().imshow(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1386, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5609, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 703, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Image data of dtype {} cannot be converted to "
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

Answer (score 1):

The code runs without any error. I think the problem is about the installation of packages or maybe input image.

[image]

Comment: I've installed opencv through cmake. I tested the above code and received the true result. I suggest  first reinstall through pip or conda. If it does'nt change try cmake.

Comment: It turns out that matplotlib is causing the problem. How do I fix it?